# Spring integration test transaction is not rolled back

Tags: java, spring, transactions, integration-testing, junit4

Writing integration test for spring based application got problem with transaction rollback - data is inserted, but after transaction rolled back, data are still in database table... 
Spring 3.0.5, JUnit 4.8.2

Integration Test code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager",defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class GenerateCodeStrategyTest {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "generateCodeStrategy")
  private Strategy generateCodeStrategy;

  @Test
  @Transactional
  public void genCodeIntegrationTestCommunicationFailure() {
  //generate some parameters
  SMPPSession mockedSession = mock(SMPPSession.class);
  generateCodeStrategy.setSession(mockedSession);
  generateCodeStrategy.sendRequest(params);
  final SubscribeInfo subscribeInfo = subscribeDao.getUserByPhone(phone);
  assertNotNull(subscribeInfo);
  assertEquals(phone, subscribeInfo.getPhone());
  assertEquals(Status.BAD_STATUS, subscribeInfo.getStatus());
  }
}
```

In DEBUG mode in logs I can see transaction started and rolled back

```
INFO: Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@1edd9b3]; rollback [true]
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into sms_subscribe (phone_cell, status, ts_subscribe, subscription_status, ts_unsubscribe, receiverIdentification, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
INFO: Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@1f18cbe testClass = GenerateCodeStrategyTest, locations = array<String>['classpath:/applicationContext.xml'], testInstance = lv.mrb.server.service.GenerateCodeStrategyTest@14f1726, testMethod = genCodeIntegrationTestCommunicationFailure@GenerateCodeStrategyTest, testException = [null]]]
```

Maybe someone have idea why this happens ? Thank you for help.

UPDATED: 
This integration test generate some parameters, then using Mockito mock of the session object is inserted into Strategy service. This mock object is just throwing exception and on this exception in that Strategy service data is saved to database via DAO layer. Then test make request to database via DAO layer and assert saved values.

Data is persisted via Hibernate so basically in my DAO object object is saved that way

```
final Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
currentSession.save(object);
```

sessionFactory is AnnotationSessionFactoryBean where datasource is c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource class

UPDATE 2 : The problem was with Mysql engine, by default it was MyISAM, so I just needed to switch it to InnoDB and now all works.

Comment: could you maybe provide the definition of your tests?

Answer (score 5):

The usual problem is that your service layer calls other layers which are also marked as `@Transactional`, perhaps even with `REQUIRES_NEW`. In that case, the Test listener only has access to the outer transaction, but has no way to roll back the inner transaction.

Often the problem is that there are `@Transactional` annotations on the DAO layer. If there are, remove them. There should be no transaction demarcation on the DAO layer.

Comment: I had @Transactional annotations in DAO layer, so I removed them all (now I have @Transactional on service layer - in my case it is sendRequest service method and also in above mentioned integration test), but still data is in database after test run successful.

Comment: @artjomka a) OK, do you have REQUIRES_NEW in your service layer? If so, it can't work b) how are you persisting your data? Hibernate, JPA, JDBC? Are you perhaps manually committing data somewhere in your DAO?

Comment: a) In service layer I have  default propagation value(REQUIRED) b) Data is persisted via Hibernate, dao is using sessionFactory to save object (Updated in question). Thank you for helping me to resolve this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@Transactional` annotation from class level and left it only for specific test methods.

Hope it helps.